# Mailchimp - Multiple Group Combinations

Tags: mailchimp, newsletter

I have this following group structure on Mailchimp:

Daily news:

- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 3
- Category 4

My subscribers can choose multiple categories to receive. My daily newsletter is built with news from all the categories. So, I need to built a newsletter for every combination of categories.

Example:

- Newsletter 1: Category 1 + Category 2 + Category 3 + Category 4
- Newsletter 2: Category 1 + Category 2 + Category 3
- Newsletter 3: Category 1 + Category 2
- ...

So, my question is: Can I build one segment for every combination? But, If my client is in a higher combination (*Newsletter 1*, for example), he can't get the *Newsletter 2*, because is the same news, without the news from *Category 4*.

And if there's no way to do that on Mailchimp, is there a way to do it with the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to exclude content for people who aren't interested in that content, you could just send one campaign but use use [conditional merge tags](https://blog.mailchimp.com/conditional-dynamic-content-in-mailchimp/) around the blocks of content to exclude it for the folks who don't want to see it. MailChimp's example in their docs:

```
*|INTERESTED:Pizza,Pie|*
This will only show up if they’re interested in pizza or pie
*|END:INTERESTED|*
```

If that won't work and you actually need to create a new segment for each one, you can combine some not-interesteds. So, instead of creating a segment that includes anyone interested in `Category 1`, you'd create a segment that includes people who are interested in `Category 1` and NOT interested in the other categories. That will keep the `Category 1` only folks from being included in your `Category 1` + `Category 2` segments.

Comment: Good one! I think that will work. Will do some tests and come back here. Thank you!